# Which IDE to use for Opa programming and how to host Opa code?

Tags: ide, hosting, opa

I am Dot Net developer and would like to try using Opa, my questions are:

1. What's a good IDE to use?
2. How to host Opa code?

Comment: Probably any good editor should do... (Eg emacs).

Answer (score 5):

You can use Sublime Text.
The plugin is [here](https://github.com/OpaOnWindowsNow/OpaSublimeText).

Answer (score 1):

Concerning IDE, check [here](http://doc.opalang.org/#!/manual/Getting-Opa/Setting-up-your-editor). Options are a bit limited at the moment but we hope to make some progress on the Eclipse IDE -- you can drop a comment in the manual with a wishlist for an IDE :).

How to host? You can try [DotCloud](http://blog.opalang.org/2011/10/programming-in-cloud-with-opa.html) or [Amazon Web Services](http://doc.opalang.org/#!/manual/Hello--scalability/Frequently-Asked-Questions).

Answer (score 1):

You can also read a tutorial to get start with Opa on dotCloud here: http://docs.dotcloud.com/services/opa/

Answer (score 1):

If you port [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/src-highlite/lang_files/opa.lang) language file to the [Gnome GtkSourceView Language Definition (v2)](http://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/rn02.html), you (we) will be able to enjoy syntax highlighting in the Gedit editor on Linux.

I'd rather see it ported to a language file for Netbeans though.

The language is great, but it really needs some more IDE support for it to catch on.

Comment: I writen a [language file](https://bitbucket.org/florent_k/opagtksourceview) for GtkSourceView.